# What is an “academic qualification concept”?

Tags: job-search, germany

I’m applying for a position in Germany but it requires an "individual qualification concept." I don’t know what this means. The job posting mentions that the "individual qualification concept" should outline "the academic qualification they are aiming for in the context of their work at the [university]."

Is this document meant to address how I meet the prerequisites for the position? Or is this a document where I address which qualifications I hope to obtain by the end of the period of the position, for instance, Juniorprofessor or Professor?

I also emailed the departmental contact for this position to ask about what they expect from a qualification but they’re out of town until next week.

If anyone has ever written one before and can give advice, or if anyone can point me in the direction of any sample essays, that would be very helpful.

Comment: You should tells us what exact position you are applying, as currently I have no idea what this individual qualification concept is.

Comment: If you translated the word it might be helpful to also post the original German word. Even if the advert you saw is in English there is a good chance a German version exists as well and then the original German word would be useful.

Comment: Here is the link to the job posting. I haven’t found the German-language posting yet but if I do, I’ll post it here. https://arthist.net/archive/39390

Comment: Here’s the German job listing, which asks for a Qualifizierungskonzept https://stelle.pro/jobposting/2142995631907f99c6ff81ce7d96060c192663a0

Comment: What else do you want to know, in addition to the paragraph in the job listing explaining what to do? "Applicants are therefore requested to submit a written application of max. 4 pages (including time schedule) outlining the academic qualification they are aiming for in the context of their work at the Academy of Media Arts. The possibility of a doctorate is given. Applications with a postdoctoral project are welcome."

Comment: I’m from the United States and we don’t have an equivalent type of statement. I don’t know if I need to state that “I hope to obtain X position at the Academy during a 6 year period,” or if that would be presumptuous. I can discuss any future book projects and other academic goals, but I don’t know if that counts as a “qualification” I am “aiming for.”

Comment: I asked my wife, who is a professor at a Fachhochschule. She says that "Qualifizierung" is a broader concept that just a qualification, it means your plan for academic development not just "will get a PhD". They want you to explain how this role fits into your wider academic career development plans.

Comment: Thanks, @JackAidley. That’s definitely helpful to think about it as overall academic development, not just as a “qualification.”